# in a directive, through parent scope's function to change parents scope's value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I write a directive, I try to change parents scope's somevalue through parent scope's function. It works fine! However, when I use a jquery plugin in the directive, through the api, I add the function in the directive, the function's work is change parents scope's somevalue. But It doesn't work! You could see my example below plnkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3pSQuS8PdJeGa5fyapVF

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you clarify the problem you see? Your example doesn't prove anything since obviously you didn't put `{{content}}` in the html. `.test()` works without problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the click event is happening outside of the angular environment. Essentially, the changes to the scope via your call to .test('abc1d') aren't been picked up by the digest.

You can force this change to be picked up by putting

```
alert(1);
s.test("abc1d");
scope.$apply(); // force angular to process your change
```